# How to make conditional PHP links?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I've searched for a way to do this, but since i'm not fluent in PHP, nothing i've tried seems to work. I have a general idea of how it should work, and it seems simple enough, but I can't get it to work the way I want it to.

Basically, I have two links on my site - each one of them links to a different style sheet, which is part of a JS style switcher. The style switcher works fine, except for one thing - I want the links to be conditional. For example, right now, my links look like this:

- Make it Dark (alternate stylesheet)
- Light it up (main stylesheet)

They both appear at once.

I'd like it to work this way: when the page loads, only the "Make it Dark" link shows. Then when it's on "Make it Dark", only a link to the Main style sheet shows.

This can be seen on the last.fm page at the very top right: http://www.last.fm/

There's two themes there: "Paint it Black" and "Simply Red". Only one link shows at a time so that you can switch between them. How would I be able to do that?

I'd appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Would it work if in each of your stylesheets you gave one of your links `display:none`?

Comment: That's definitely the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a class on both off them and than add a display: none in the opposite stylesheet to hide it for the user. So you have:

```
<a href="" class="darken">Make it dark</a>
<a href="" class="lighten">Light it up</a>
```

And in the two stylesheets you have in the dark one:

```
.lighten { display: none; }
```

And in the light one:

```
.darken { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd use a session variable and not a cookie.

Something like this should work:

```
<?php
session_start(); // add to the top of your page
if (!isset($_SESSION['dark_theme'])) {
  $_SESSION['dark_theme']==false;
}

if ($_GET['changetheme']!='') {
  if ($_GET['changetheme']=='dark') {
    $_SESSION['dark_theme']=true;
  } else {
    $_SESSION['dark_theme']=false;
  }
}
?>
```

This bit, place where you want the link:

```
<?php
if(!$_SESSION['dark_theme']){
?>
<a href="?changetheme=dark" id="darken">Make it Dark</a>
<?
}else{
 ?>
<a href="?changetheme=light" id="lighten">Make it Light</a>
<?
}
?>
```

Or do it using CSS+JavaScript:

The HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="darken">Make it Dark</a>
<a href="#" id="lighten">Make it Light</a>
```

The CSS:

In your "dark" stylesheet:

```
#darken {
  display:none;
}
```

In your "light" stylesheet:

```
#lighten {
  display:none;
}
```

JavaScript (note, I'm using JQuery as it's much easier to write than normal JS - just you'll need to include JQuery if it's not already on the site):

```
(function($, undefined)
{
  $('#darken').click(function() {
    $(this).preventDefault(); // stops the link from functioning as a link
    chooseStyle('none', 60); //call your change stylesheet function
    $('#darken').hide(); //hide the dark link
    $('#lighten').show(); // show the light link
  })

  $('#lighten').click(function() {
    $(this).preventDefault(); // stops the link from functioning as a link
    chooseStyle('none', 60); //call your change stylesheet function
    $('#lighten').hide(); //hide the light link
    $('#darken').show(); // show the dark link
  })
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: hi, thanks for this. I have decided to use PHP instead of CSS because I want to maintain the selected style sheet upon reloading the page. The only problem is, this php example doesn't seem to work correctly ... and I don't know enough PHP to trouble shoot the issue.  ;[ In this code, the "make it dark" link doesn't show and kind of messes up my css header code at the top.

Comment: Sorry, had slight errors in the code (was doubling the = sign when trying to set the session variable).
I have edited the code above, should work fine now. If not pass me a link and I'd be more than happy to help.

Comment: Also just tidied up the code a bit, sorry, must have been in a rush when I wrote this originally.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for helping. The links work as intended now, except for the fact that the style sheet changer uses javascript. So inside the href for the link that changes the style sheet is " javascript:chooseStyle('none', 60)". How would I intergrate that into the PHP code? also ... is there a way to fix how the links are formatted in the PHP code? because right now, the links from the PHP code are hidden underneath my logo, and for some reason, it is messing with my css header because I think the PHP code placed at the top is making a huge space where there should not be one.

Comment: The link you can move around anywhere on the page - just take the block of code that starts from this bit to the end:
if (!$_SESSION['dark_theme']) {

Place that if/else statement wherever you want the link to be.
You can also change the HTML to suit (e.g. put an id or a class on it to style it).

As for the JavaScript, you'd need to add quite a bit more to it to change the stylesheet that way, and doing it with JS you might as well just use CSS to hide/show the correct link instead of PHP.

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify what you mean by "just take the block of code that starts from this bit to the end: if (!$_SESSION['dark_theme']) { Place that if/else statement wherever you want the link to be." I keep getting parse errors when I do that. The JS script is what changes the style sheet, is there is a way to do it with CSS?

Comment: I've edited the post above to split the code out a bit, should explain what I mean better.

There is a way to do it client side (i.e. HTML/CSS/JS), which I've also added into the answer above.

Other than that I don't know how I can make it any clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_COOKIES['dark_theme']){
 $show_dark = true;
}else{
 $show_dark = false;
}


if($show_dark){
 echo "<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/dark.css"...";
}else{
 echo "<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/light.css"...";
}
```

When you click "make it dark", just reload the page and modify the cookie.

Comment: Hi, thank you all for the help. I have decided to use PHP instead of CSS because I want to maintain the selected style sheet upon reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can tell php to do this in one line, you just need to set cookie when user is switching to another stylesheet change below cookie name according to your need.

```
echo (isset($_COOKIE['dark_theme'])) ? '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/dark.css">' : '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/light.css">';
```